Major display and application loading lag after Nvidia driver installed
I have an eGPU that I want to use with my laptop. My laptop has an integrated Intel graphics card. Everything works perfectly fine with the Intel card and my desktop without the use of the eGPU.
However, after I installed the Nvidia driver via "nvidia-driver firmware-misc-nonfree", my applications lag and delay in loading. I do not have the eGPU plugged in when this happens, and I rebooted with the eGPU unplugged to be sure that it wasn't accessible either. When the egpu is plugged in with the Nvidia driver this does not happen.
No Nvidia driver and no egpu: no lag
Nvidia driver with egpu: no lag
Nvidia driver with egpu unplugged: lag
In the first video, you can see the graphical distortion and the time it takes to load Chrome (over 10 seconds). And the second video shows how quickly Chrome loads when I uninstall the Nvidia drivers and use nouveau again without the eGPU:
https://imgur.com/a/CKfZWmU
I'm running Debian 12 with the Nvidia 535.183.01 driver. I'm using XFCE as my desktop environment.

I had to stop recommending Linux for machines with modern NVIDIA graphics cards.  Too many crashes and other issues.  I find Linux is amazing on older hardware, but the compatibility problems between Linux and modern NVIDIA graphics cards caused too many significant issues.  Hopefully someday NVIDIA and Linux will work well together.
